# Notepad++ Print Selection?

Tags: printing, notepad++

Is there a way to print just the selected lines (or a range of lines) in my source document? I could cut and paste a selection to a new Notepad++ tab, but then I lose the line numbers!

Comment: ...  What happens when you choose the "print selected" option from the Print menu that comes up when you choose print?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [works the same way for most any application](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/uncategorized/print-only-selected-text-from-web-pages/), it is a setting in the print dialog. Should look something like this:

[image]

Also, I have tested it - the line numbers are preserved.